# I have image of laptop with empty background. How can I fill only that specific empty part of image with some background color?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to fill that empty background with color, also that background should be responsible with the image. Can be done with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)  gradient(or an image), `background-size`, `background-position`  and `no-repeat` to set it under the area of the screen.

example:

```css
img {
  background: /*linear-gradient(blue,blue)*/
  /* choose the gradient for a color, see hover effect */
  /* or use an image of the appropriate ratio */
  url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/102/1129/751.jpg?hmac=uS-7B0eUG3Sd1mZHONp80fqhpDZ6g09ZoD7aw7l8tAo) 50% 1%/ 80% 80% no-repeat;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 70%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px silver)
}

img:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, blue);
}

html {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #444
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu2YY.png>
```

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) can also be used if you want to add a shadow (or else) effect.

Answer (score 0):

you want this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>

        .main{
            position: relative;
        }
      
           .bg-color {
    background-color: rgb(177, 50, 50);
    height: 251px;
    width: 447px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 168px;
    top: 16px;
}

        .img
        {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 0;
            left: 8%;
        }

        

        @media (min-width:500px) and (max-width:900px){
            .bg-color {
                background-color: rgb(177, 50, 50);
                height: 251px;
                width: 452px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                left: 96px;
                top: 16px;}
        }
        
        @media (min-width:700px) and (max-width:1300px){
            .bg-color {
                background-color: rgb(177, 50, 50);
                height: 251px;
                width: 452px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                left: 156px;
                top: 16px;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="bg-color">
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/48/ce/e8/48cee83121a363a248640dbf54778d87.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is still on little left, try shifting it a little right

Answer (score 0):

In the same as you used do background color using background-color property look at these image with transparent background with two different colors in the background color. the only difference is that the image you are using doesn't have the transparent background.

```
img {
background-image: black;
}
```

[image]

```
img{
background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

[image]

Comment: With this approach the OP will have the color around the laptop, too …